# Residue calculation for $z^{-2}\sin(z^{-2})$

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus, cauchy-integral-formula

I am trying to calculate the residue of $f(z) = \frac{1}{z^2}\sin\left(\frac{1}{z^2}\right)$ at $z=0$. Looking at the Taylor expansion of $f$ around $0$, as $c_{-n}$ (the coefficients of the powers of $z$) is non-zero for infinitely many $n$, $z=0$ must be a essential singularity of the function. However, as the expansion does not contain a term proportional to $\frac{1}{z}$, does this just mean $\text{Res}_{z=0}f(z) = 0$ by the definition of the Residue? This doesn't feel correct.

Comment: It is correct. This is an even function, so its Laurent series about $0$ is also even, i.e. the coefficients of odd powers of $z$ are all $0$.  In particular the residue at $z=0$ is indeed $0$.

Comment: You can as well do it directly. Substituting $z=u^{-1}$ gives $$\oint\limits_{|z|=1}z^{-2}\sin(z^{-2})\,dz =-\oint\limits_{|u|=1}\sin(u^2)\,du=0$$